# how do I connect mongoDB to a Dataiku dataset?

Tags: mongodb, data-science-studio

This question is about **Dataiku** **DSS** .

I'm having trouble opening a mongoDB collection and connecting it as a dataset in Dataiku.

There's an option of using Python script but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very late answer but the following page explains how to connect to mongoDB in Dataiku DSS:
https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/connecting/dss-and-mongodb.html

You have to be administrator of the instance.
The main steps are:

- Go to Administration->Connections
- New connection->MongoDB
- Fill the Host, Database name, User, Password fields
- Grant the appropriate rights (probably write access, and specific groups).
- Click the Test button to make sure everything is ok, then save it.

Comment: Please post the main parts of the page in your answer. If in a future that external link is broken the answer won't be valid. Thank you